# Append dataframe error while using a function which returns a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am unable to append a dataframe for every value that is passed from one dataframe. Following is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import io

header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.106 Safari/537.36',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9'}

def gethistoricaldata(symbol):
    url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/getHistoricalData.jsp?symbol="+str(symbol)+"&series=EQ&fromDate=undefined&toDate=undefined&datePeriod=3months"
    urlData = requests.get(url, headers = header).content
    df = pd.read_html(urlData)
    df1 = df[0]
    df1 = df1[['Date','Symbol','Close Price']]
    table = df1.copy()
    table['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(table.Date)
    table = table.pivot(index='Symbol', columns='Date', values='Close Price')
    return table

List = pd.DataFrame({'Underlying': ['VEDL', 'AMARAJABAT', 'ZEEL']})

df = pd.DataFrame([])
for symbol in List.items():
    df = df.append(gethistoricaldata(i))


print(df)
```

The function works when I pass only 1 value. But I need to append the dataframe passed through the defined function for every value in the dataframe "List" and create/returns a new dataframe.

Desired dataframe is below:

```
Date    2019-12-04  2019-12-05  2019-12-06  2019-12-09  
Symbol                                                                          ...
VEDL          63.75        62.3        60.2        60.8  
AMARAJABAT    63.75        62.3        60.2        60.8 
ZEEL          63.75        62.3        60.2        60.8
```

Comment: It would be faster and likely easier to debug if you were to collect all your returned dataframes in a list, then afterwards, use `pd.concat` or `pd.merge` on that list.

Comment: Welcome to DS StackExchange. It seems this is a question for Stackoverflow, and a bit off-topic for Data Science.

Comment: Thanks...was able to get the solution